# Django template generation time

Tags: django, statistics, django-templates

How can I measure time taken for template generation?
I know i can collect time `Context.render()` takes but can i do it unobtrusive way? Something like [Page Stats Middleware](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PageStatsMiddleware) do for Python and DB time... But split Python time to code/view time and template time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could swap old render method to your own like this:

```
old_render = Context.render

def new_render(self, *args, **kwargs):
  # do some profiling
  old_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  # do some profiling

Context.render = new_render
```

This shouldn't be very obtrusive and you can remove it anytime you won't - it doesn't change interface.

I don't believe you can use `middleware`, because `middleware` works before `request` is passed to a `view` - and you render a template inside a view.